# ChimpChat Instrumentation

Tags: android, automation, monkeyrunner

I am trying to use chimpchat from a java program. I am able to successfully establish connection with two emulator instances running. But when i call instrument() function on the device, to run a test suite,the program crashes with a null-pointer exception. Could anyone please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

chimpchat is supposed to be running on host machine, not on device, so you cannot use instrment() along with it.